# R string detect return partial value and create a column

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame as indicated in column V1 and I need to check if there is a partial match and if I find the partial match, create a new column with that value.
I have used the code below, but is definetly not right as I need to catch all those with the partial match. Sorry, I am new.
I am really struggling :( also I am trying to set a specific range, like all N_ but from for example 20-30, and code doesnt work

```
olDF
V1                      
(N_R32,N_A35,B_W33)
```

```
newDataFrame = olDF %>%
  mutate(New col = case_when(
    str_detect(V1, "N_R32") ~ "N_R32",
  ))
```

Desired output

```
V1                       New col
(N_R32,N_A35,B_W33)    N_R32, N_A35
```

Thanks to suggestion this is doing the trick but partially, I need to set a specific range of N_ for example 30-40, but the code below picks also things like N_R19B. How do I change the code to set it at the needed range?

```
library(stringr)
x = "N_R32,N_A35,B_W33, NR32B"
str_extract_all(x, "N_([A-Z]|[0-9])+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "N_R32" "N_A35"
```

Comment: can you give a small reproducible example of what `olDF` looks like, and exactly what the match condition is and how it leads to the desired output?

Comment: OldF is only column V1

Comment: so what is the rule to generate `N_R32, N_A35` from this?

Comment: I don't know, I have this file and need to extract words startinf with N__  and create a new column based on this

Comment: I have ((N_R32,N_A35,B_W33)  and need to extract all that matches N_

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for `str_extract()` instead of `str_detect()`:

```
library(stringr)
x = "N_R32,N_A35,B_W33, NR32B"
str_extract_all(x, "N_([A-Z]|[0-9])+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "N_R32" "N_A35"
```

Comment: It partially works, I have some things like N_R32A and NR32B, how do I fix the code to include them?

Comment: You can make the `_` optional with `?`, see update

Comment: It's picking also things starting with NS for example, when I only need N_  :(

Comment: `NR32B` is not `N_`...

Comment: APOLOGIES! was a typo, I only need N_ really sorry

Comment: Many thanks for all your help! I am really struggling to add a range. How do I change the code to set it at the needed range, such as only N_ from 30 to 40?

Comment: Thanks, I opened another question, I am not too sure how to solve this but any comment is acceted. thanks again